# githu.dev consumes too much cpu. is this normal?

Tags: github

Steps to reproduce:

Go to a GitHub repo(e.g. https://github.com/go-playground/webhooks)

Press `.`

or

Go to https://github.dev/go-playground/webhooks

htop output:
[image]

Browser Task Manager:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to vscode.dev 
Click on "Open remote repository" 
Enter the username/repo-name

Or go straight to: vscode.dev/github/username/repo-name

After realize the the cpu overheat cause by github.dev, I switch to vscode.dev with no more overheat.